# Decrease the number of mouseover triggered events

Tags: javascript, jquery

> How can i decrease the number of mouse over triggered events?
>   I still want to use mouse over but with less amount of event triggers.

```
$(clientFrameWindow.document.body).on("mouseover",function () {
//it should be 15 times slow down than now.
console.log(1);


});
```

i am using jQuery.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't assign it to body, everytime your mouse moves from one element to another its going to fire a mouseover event and bubble up to body. Target only the element(s) you want a mouseover on.

Comment: i am targeting it to body because i need to capture other elements as i am developing a drag and drop app..thats why i need it..
please see the question again..

Comment: The [ondragover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondragover) and other [drag events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) might work much better for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you **must** use the listener on `body`, as per your comment, I would suggest you consider something like throttling or debouncing.

Read this for more info: https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/

Here's a simple throttling implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/m7G64/

I would also suggest you remove the overhead of jQuery on this one and simply do an `addEventListener('mouseover', function(){})`

EDIT: Also, since you want it for drag and dropping on the `body`, from, I assume, your OS environment, maybe could use `mouseenter` event instead of `mouseover`? It's definitely cheaper.

Comment: "reduce the event trigger speed" Well, throttling and debouncing do that. Also, check out my answer, updated it.